# Android scroll last visible ListItem until it is completely visible

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with list items that can expand when pressing on them. If I press the last visible item of the list the expanded part isn't shown. How could I scroll the list view so the completely view is shown after it was expanded?

Comment: Are you using multiple view types for your list view?

Comment: No, its a LinearLayout with a few hidden views inside, like e.g. a progress bar

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem partially with following code:

```
if (listItemView != null) {
  Rect listViewRect = new Rect();
  Rect listItemRect = new Rect();
  getListView().getHitRect(listViewRect);
  listItemView.getHitRect(listItemRect);
  int bottom = listItemRect.bottom + listItemView.getHeight();
  if (bottom > listViewRect.bottom) {
    int y = bottom - listViewRect.bottom;
    getListView().scrollTo(getListView().getScrollX(), y);
  }
}
```

One problem remaining now is that when you call scrollTo and then you press with your finger the list like when you want to scroll it, the list is scrolled back to the position before you called scrollTo.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but what happens, if you call scrollTo(Integer.MAX_VALUE)?

Comment: but it's not the last item, it is the last visible item that I mean

Comment: Oh I was misled by the title saying "Android scroll last ListItem"